# WPF Using of Frame

Tags: visual-studio, .net, c#, wpf

While I'm using frame in Mainwindow , initially i hide an item in Mainwindows.
When i pressed a button in frame Page1 , I want to make item in mainwindow as visible.But i can't do it.I tried to updatelayout() , refresh() functions but anything is changed.Anyone has a knowledge about this??

This code is in MainWindow

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                müsteributton.IsEnabled = false;
                string yer = "Pages/kullanicigiris.xaml";
                frame1.Source = new Uri(yer, UriKind.Relative);
                frame1.Margin = new Thickness(-175, 0, 0, 0);

            }
```

This code is in kullanicigiris page

```
 private void Dispatcher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 2)
            {

                dispatcher.Stop();
                frm1 = new MainWindow();
                 frm1.frame1 = null;
                DependencyObject currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
                while (currParent != null && frm1.frame1 == null)
                {
                    frm1.frame1 = currParent as Frame;
                    currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currParent);
                }

                // Change the page of the frame.
                if (frm1.frame1 != null)
                {
                    frm1.frame1.Source = new Uri("Window1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    frm1.müsteributton.IsEnabled = true;
                }


            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me is to make sure that you are not creating a new MainWindow, if that is the case it is not your original MainWindow and any changes you make to it will not be reflected back to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) in the MainWindows.

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="399" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Show/ Hide" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SetVisibilityProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("SetVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(Mainfreampage), new
        PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, null));

    public Visibility SetVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(SetVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SetVisibilityProperty, value); } 
    }
```

In your page click event, you can use the following code find the MainWindows and change the DependencyProperty value.

```
  var mw = Application.Current.Windows
.Cast<Mainfreampage>()
.FirstOrDefault(window => window is Mainfreampage) as Mainfreampage;


  mw.SetVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is here:

```
frm1 = new MainWindow();
```

You are creating a brand new window, and then making your changes in that window.

But: **that's not the window the user's looking at!**

Taking the approach you've embarked on, your frame code needs to keep track of the `Window` object it's actually being hosted in, and then use *that* reference for dealing with the update.

That said, that entire approach is flawed. The navigation should be modeled in a view model data structure, activated via an `ICommand` object, and optionally via timer (as you seem to be doing here). Frame source and button state can be manipulated through bindings to properties in your view model data structure.

But, at the end of the day, the code you've got should work fine, once you start using the correct `Window` object.